# hot to make shortcut for converter plugin in notepad++?

Tags: plugins, notepad++

i mostly use conversion plugin for converting text to HEX and back. these functionalities are planted in menus. and they are hard to reach.

[image]
as far as i know there is no shortcut for doing so. i want to write a plugin to do so.
how can i do that?
can any one make an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hit "settings" > "shortcut mapper" > "plugin commands" and you can set your own shortcut.